# Intuition Behind Difference-in-Differences with Continuous Treatment?

Tags: regression, statistics, difference-in-difference

It's very clear to me how a difference-in-difference model works when there is a binary treatment. If the model is $y_{i,t}=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}P_{t}+\beta_{2}T_{i}+\beta_{3}(P_{t}*T_{t})+u_{i,t}$ where $P_{t}$ is a dummy for the time period after a policy and $T_{i}$ is a dummy for the treatment. It is clear that difference-in-differences will give us $\beta_{3}$ as the average differential change in $y$ from one period to the next relative to the control group $\bigg(\big((\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}+\beta_{2}+\beta_{3})-(\beta_{0}+\beta_{2})\big)-\big((\beta_{0}+\beta_{1})-\beta_{0}\big)\bigg)=\beta_{3}$.

I'm currently studying a model, however, that looks like the following: $y_{i,t}=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}(\Delta T*P_{t})+u_{i,t}$ where $\Delta T$ is the change in education funding from a year before a certain policy to a year after a certain policy and is continuous. In this case, how do I show that this is still using the difference-in-difference approach as before? I'm struggling to see the link.